# Dynamic NamedDatabase in Play Framework

Tags: database, multi-tenant, playback

I'm running a java play framework setup where I would like to have several databases depending on what customer is making the call. I have a jwt setup where there is a tenant id. However I can't get my head around what's best practise in Play regarding this. As for now I have this code:

```
public class JavaNamedDatabase {
  private Database db;
  private DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext;
  private static final Logger.ALogger LOGGER = Logger.of(JavaNamedDatabase.class);


  @Inject
  public JavaNamedDatabase(
      @NamedDatabase("xxx") Database db, DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext) {
    this.db = db;
    this.executionContext = executionContext;
  }
```

where I would like to make "xxx" dynamic depending on which tenant is making the request.
Is it possible to pass this parameter or do I need to have separate classes?

Or maybe the best solution is just to have one instance running per customer and have the @NamedDatabase as a runtime config parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I found DBApi where there is a getter for Database.

````
public class JavaNamedDatabase {
  private DBApi dbApi;
  private DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext;
  private static final Logger.ALogger LOGGER = Logger.of(JavaNamedDatabase.class);


  @Inject
  public JavaNamedDatabase(
      DBApi dbApi, DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext) {
    this.dbApi = dbApi;
    this.executionContext = executionContext;
  }

  public CompletionStage<Integer> addGenreToPlayItem(Integer playItemId, String genre) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () ->
            dbApi.getDatabase("xxx").withConnection(...```
````